# jQuery - Why creating object with class by string ($('<div class="foo" />')) is slower than creating same object and execute addClass() method?

Tags: jquery, class, append, jsperf

Can anyone may explain me **why creating object via string is slower than same object and execute addClass() method in jQuery?**

I thought that addClass() method will be slower, but it is not. I'm wondering why?

Look at this jsPerf - http://jsperf.com/jquery-append-with-class-and-with-method-addclass

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because only passing an element name, like `$("<div>")`, maps to a call to [document.createElement()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createElement).

On the other hand, passing an element and its attributes, like `$("<div class='foo'>")`, maps to a call to [document.createDocumentFragment()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createDocumentFragment), which is slower than `createElement()` followed by a write to the `className` property.

Comment: Good point. Does this apply to the `$("<div>", {"class":"foo"})` approach as well? Looking at [the benchmarks](http://jsperf.com/jquery-append-with-class-and-with-method-addclass/2) it's still slower than `.addClass()`.

Comment: This also applies to that code (it will result in a call to `createElement()`), but iterating over a hash of attributes and performing the associated calls to `attr()` is still slower than a single call to `addClass()`.

Comment: Thanks guys, now I know. Besides for me (Chrome 15 on MAC) adding class via {} take the same time as .addClass()

Answer (score 3):

I would say that `$('<div class=“foo” />')` takes time because it has to parse the HTML string, then perform the `addClass()` (or internal equivalent) anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I tried adding a third test case with

```
viaObject = $("<div>", { class: "foo-"+counterN });
biz.append(viaObject);
counterN++;
```

that i thought should have been as fast as `$("<div>").addClass("foo-")` for the reason pointed out by Frédéric Hamidi  (document.createElement() vs  document.createDocumentFragment()) but it still slower.

Probably addClass() is faster than accessing properties of an object.

In any case this proves that you should create your element like this

```
 $("<div>", { class: "foo-"+counterN });
```

and not like this:

```
 $('<div class="foo-' + counterS + '" />');
```

Comment: Yup. See comments in Frederic's answer.